# QML function called from onPropertyChanged pauses and resumes later

Tags: qml

I am new to QML. I am working on onPropertyChanged I found that function started from `onPropertyChanged` pauses and resumes again.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
        QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                        &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Datapool.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    id: datapol
    property int data1: 1
    property int data2: 1
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: "red"

    Datapool {
        id: datapool
        objectName: "datpole"
    }

    property int property1: datapool.data1
    property int property2: datapool.data2

    property var title1: { 'title': 'title 1' }
    property var title2: { 'title': 'title 2' }
    property var title3: { 'title': 'title 3' }
    property var title4: { 'title': 'title 4' }
    
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        id: grid
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.leftMargin: 372 / 2
        spacing: 324 / 2

        Repeater {
            model: listModel
            delegate: Text {
                text: model.title
            }
        }
    }

    onProperty1Changed: {
        updateList("property1")
    }

    onProperty2Changed: {
        updateList("property2")
    }

    function updateList(name)
    {
        console.log("updateList start", name)
        listModel.clear();

        if (property1 == 1) {
            console.log("updateList title 1", name)
            listModel.append(title1);
        }
        if (property2 == 1) {
            console.log("updateList title 2", name)
            listModel.append(title2);
        }
        console.log("updateList end", name)
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
qml: updateList start property1
qml: updateList title 1 property1
qml: updateList start property2
qml: updateList title 1 property2
qml: updateList title 2 property2
qml: updateList end property2
qml: updateList title 2 property1
qml: updateList end property1
```

From the log, property1 started first but property2 is finishing first

What is the reason and how it can be synchronized.

Thanks.

Also printed the qDebug() << "The current thread is " << QThread::currentThread();

It is printing same thread id for both `propertyChanged`

Comment: please provide [mcve] so we can run and test it

Comment: @folibis Updated with example code. Please check it once

Comment: It seems using timer fixing the issue.  timer is started only after both onProperty1&2Changed are called